# $F \times G$ as defined is indeed a product in $A^I$, $ \ A $ an additive category.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, additive-categories

Trying to prove: $F \times G$ is a product in $A^I$.  It has been defined as $(F\times G)(i) = F(i) \times G(i)$ and $(F\times G)(f) = $ unique map $F(i) \times G(i) \to F(j) \times G(j)$ described in the UMP of products in $A$.

$\pi^F : F \times G \to F$, sim $G$, are natural maps and for each $i \xrightarrow{f} j$ in $I$, $\pi^F_i : F(i) \times G(i) \to F(i)$, sim $G$, are such that for any natural maps $\eta^F: H \to F$, $ \ \eta^G : H \to G$ there exists a family of maps in $A$, $\eta : H \to F \times G$ such that $\pi^F \eta = \eta^F$, $ \ \pi^G \eta = \eta^G$.

How do I show that $\eta$ is a natural map?

Comment: For sources you could take a look at [the joy of cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) in chapter 10. You will find info about monosources. The projections of a product form a monosources (proposition 10.21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the naturality of $\eta$ it is enough to exhibit for an
arbitrary arrow $f:i\to j$ in $I$ that:  $$\left(Ff\times Gf\right)\circ\eta_{i}=\eta_{j}\circ Hf$$

We have:

$$\pi_{j}^{F}\circ\left(Ff\times Gf\right)\circ\eta_{i}=Ff\circ\pi_{i}^{F}\circ\eta_{i}=Ff\circ\eta_{i}^{F}=\eta_{j}^{F}\circ Hf=\pi_{j}^{F}\circ\eta_{j}\circ Hf$$

The first equality as a consequence of the naturality of $\pi^{F}$
and the third as a consequence of the naturality of $\eta^{F}$.

Likewise we find:

$$\pi_{j}^{G}\circ\left(Ff\times Gf\right)\circ\eta_{i}=Ff\circ\pi_{i}^{G}\circ\eta_{i}=Ff\circ\eta_{i}^{G}=\eta_{j}^{G}\circ Hf=\pi_{j}^{G}\circ\eta_{j}\circ Hf$$

on base of the naturality of $\pi^{G}$ and $\eta^{G}$.

Source $\left(\pi_{j}^{F},\pi_{j}^{G}\right)$is a mono-source so
we are allowed to conclude that indeed: $$\left(Ff\times Gf\right)\circ\eta_{i}=\eta_{j}\circ Hf$$

Comment: How do you get to work with $(Ff \times Gf)$?  That never came about with my studying...  And what do you mean by 'Source'?

Comment: $Ff\times Gf=(F\times G)f$.

Comment: That must be by definition, right?

Comment: Yes. Just as $Fi\times Gi$ is by definition $(F\times G)i$ when it comes to objects.

Comment: Can $\pi^F_j$ monic be proved easily with my elementary tools?

Comment: Two (are more arrows) $f,g$ are called "source" if they have the same domain. One speaks of monosource of $f\circ u=f\circ v\wedge g\circ u=g\circ v$ implies that $u=v$. $\pi^F_j$ on its own is not monic, but together with $\pi^G_j$ it forms a source that is a monosource.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @drhab for your explanation. I will try to elaborate here for understanding.

$\pi_i^F : F(i) \times G(i) \to F(i)$ is monic

If we have:
$$
k \xrightarrow{e_1, e_2} F(i) \times G(i) \xrightarrow{\pi^F_i} F(i) \\
k \xrightarrow{e_1, e_2} F(i) \times G(i) \xrightarrow{\pi^G_i} G(i)
$$

Then by definition of product in $A$, there exists a unique map $k \xrightarrow{e} F(i) \times G(i)$ such that $\pi_i^F e = (\pi_i^F e_1 = \pi_i^F e_2)$, sim $G$, $\implies e_2 = e = e_1$, sim $G$.

Comment: $\pi_i^F$ is *not monic* in this context, but $(\pi_i^F,\pi_i^G)$ is a monosource.

Comment: If $e_{1}:k\rightarrow Fi$ and $e_{2}:k\rightarrow Gi$ then there
is a unique $e:k\to Fi\times Gi$ such that $e_{1}=\pi_{i}^{F}\circ e$
and $e_{2}=\pi_{i}^{G}\circ e$.

The uniqueness of $e$ corresponds with the notion that $\left(\pi_{i}^{F},\pi_{i}^{G}\right)$
is a monosource: if also $e_{1}=\pi_{i}^{F}\circ e'$ and $e_{2}=\pi_{i}^{G}\circ e'$
then $\pi_{i}^{F}\circ e=\pi_{i}^{F}\circ e'$ and $\pi_{i}^{G}\circ e=\pi_{i}^{G}\circ e'$
resulting in $e=e'$.